# invalid object in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Everytime I create a stored procedure and press f5 it says command executed successfully but when i click on the procedure name and click execute ,it prompts me for parameters but then says invalid object name for the stored procedure name.Cant make out why is this happening.

```
 USE [MIND]
 GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[NAME]    Script Date: 20-09-2013 22:29:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[NAME]  @delivery_status varchar(10),@startdate date,@enddate date
AS
select * from deliverydata 
where deliverydata.delivery_status=@delivery_status and Date in (@startdate,@enddate)
```

Comment: Can you execute it by writing the `EXEC` statement yourself?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get back?